# Neural Network size of input matrix versus size of synaptic matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, neural-network, deep-learning

I am studying the code example at: A Neural Network in 11 lines of Python

In line 22, do I understand correctly that syn0 is a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns?  If so, why?  The X matrix, created in lines 9-11, has a size of 4x3, so I would have expected syn0 in line 22 to ALSO have that same size, so that each value in X could be multiplied by a weight value in syn0.  My best guess is this: we want to multiply X, a 4x3 matrix, by syn0, a 3x4 matrix, without having to transpose, so the code below saves us from transposing.  What am I missing?  Here is the code, followed by a table that may shed clues:

```
    01.import numpy as np
    02. 
    03.def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    04.  if(deriv==True):
    05.    return x*(1-x)
    06. 
    07.  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    08. 
    09.X = np.array([[0,0,1],
    10.             [0,1,1],
    11.             [1,0,1],
    12.             [1,1,1]])
    13. 
    14.y = np.array([[0],
    15.             [1],
    16.             [1],
    17.             [0]])
    18. 
    19.np.random.seed(1)
    20. 
    21.# randomly initialize our weights with mean 0
    22.syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
    23.syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
```

Why does this table, provided with the code, show a 4x4 matrix of hidden weights for layer 1?:

Inputs(l0)  Hidden Weights(l1)  Output (l2)
0   0   1   0.1 0.2 0.5 0.2     0
0   1   1   0.2 0.6 0.7 0.1     1
1   0   1   0.3 0.2 0.3 0.9     1
1   1   1   0.2 0.1 0.3 0.8     0
Thanks for your help, David

Comment: Not entirely sure of my diagnosis - but this sounds like a confusion between element-wise multiplication of two matrices, and actual matrix multiplication. Here we are doing matrix mult of the weights and the input X, not element-wise. Hence a 4x3 times a 3x4 will give a 4x4 output

Comment: How can we answer without seeing what happens with `syn0` and `X`?

Comment: Spinodal, I very much appreciate your guidance.  I think your diagnosis is correct, and I've gone back to the drawing board to make sure I know what size and why of each step along the way.  I'm still not clear on when or why one needs element-wise multiplication at all, so if you have any thoughts on that, I'd be grateful.  Warmly, David